# How to make an svg icon (which uses <use> ) a link

Tags: html, svg, icons

So I have these small svg icons like below code:

```
                <svg class="icon icon-instagram">
                    <use xlink:href="img/symbol-defs.svg#icon-instagram"></use>
                </svg>
```

I need to make these icons a clickable link. I've looked at similar questions but some suggested changing it to img (then I wouldn't be able to use the fill css property) and some suggested using a text inside the svg tag. 
Is there a way that we can make these icons links and not sacrifice other properties?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just wrap it in a <a> tag?

Comment: It doesn't work. That was my first try.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a xlink:href="https://stackoverflow.com/">
  <text x="10" y="25">Stackoverflow</text>
</a>
```

Comment: While this answer might be technically correct please provide a context as to how this answer could be used and why you think it would be correct.